# Following haskell lecture but code not working

Tags: haskell

I'm following along in a lecture using haskell and wrote a simple function

```
getNth :: Int -> [a] -> a
getNth n (x:xs) = if n == 0 then x else getNth (n-1) xs
```

however, I'm getting the error

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for `getNth':
    Patterns of type `Int', `[a]' not matched: _ []
```

I wrote exactly what my prof wrote in lecture, am i missing something?

When i try to run in GHCi it also isnt working

Answer (score 5):

Unless you enabled `-Werror` without telling us, the message you got is just a warning, not an error, and your `getNth` function will work exactly like the built-in `!!` function. Both your function and that function are dangerous in that they are *partial*: they'll fail for some inputs. But for an appropriate input, it will work fine. E.g., `getNth 2 "abcde"` will return `'c'`. If it's not working for you in GHCi, I expect that you passed an invalid input, like `getNth 5 "abcde"`.

Answer (score 2):

`(x:xs)` matches a list with one or elements. Your code does not handle the empty list pattern `[]`. Since you can't find an element at any index in an empty list, you might throw an exception, or you might return `Maybe a`, with `Nothing` indicating no such index existing.

```
getNth :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
getNth _ [] = Nothing
getNth 0 (x:_) = Just x
getNth n (_:xs) = getNth (n-1) xs
```

```
Prelude> getNth 3 [2,3,4]
Nothing
Prelude> getNth 3 [2,3,4,5,6]
Just 5
Prelude> getNth 0 []
Nothing
```